# Watch file and automatically upload file to remote server PHP Storm

Tags: javascript, php, ide, gruntjs, phpstorm

I am using Grunt.js to watch my `js` and `scss` files which compiles them to `main.js` and `main.css` when saved. This all works fine.

Annoyingly though, to see the changes reflected on my server I need to manually go to the `main.js` and `main.css` files on my local directory, right click and select `upload to ...` my remote server.

This is quite an ugly bump in my otherwise smooth workflow.

Is it possible to setup a task either though PHP Storm or Grunt.js to automatically upload these files if and when they are changed?

Comment: It is possible, as you can trigger any program with Grunt (remember that grunt is just a regular node.js app). But you should try first, as it is, this is a very vague question.

Comment: You could also use phing or any other build tool to automate that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a task called [grunt-ftp-deploy](https://github.com/zonak/grunt-ftp-deploy) that you can configure to upload any files to the server. Basically it would be something like

```
'ftp-deploy': {
  build: {
    auth: {
      host: 'yourserver',
      port: 21,
      authKey: 'key'
    },
    src: 'dist/',
    dest: '/path/to/destination/folder',
    exclusions: !['path/to/dist/main.js', 'path/to/dist/main.js']
  }
}
```

This will exclude all the files except the ones you want to upload. You will also need to create a file called `.ftppass` that contain the ftp credentials like this:

```
{
  "key": {
    "username": "username1",
    "password": "password1"
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add this file to your `.gitignore` because ftp information are sensitive.

Now you can add the task `ftp-deploy` to the end of your build task like this:

```
  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    ...
    'ftp-deploy'
  ]);
```

but this approach will upload your files everytime you make a build. You can also run that task manually from the terminal using `grunt ftp-deploy`.

There is a very similar task called [grunt-sftp-deploy](https://github.com/thrashr888/grunt-sftp-deploy) just in case you are using sftp.